# php Load subjects withe looping throug users object

Tags: php

i am a biginner in php  and i have started building my project but this problem stops me ..

look at my function

my problem is i use load subjects in order in a page but after load it i need from each user to have 25 subjects if he/she have this ammount of subjects in DB to appear in the page in order so in my case some users have only one subject and the others have more than 25 subject then the user that have one subject if he is shown at the end of the page in first load of the page then the rest of the other subjects will be dessappear untill i press the view more btn 
but acually what i need is to have orderd subjects as it is made by one user ? any help ??

:)

```
public static function getsubjects($users){
      $output = array();         
      foreach ($users as $key => $fo){
          $sql ="SELECT * FROM  supject_content WHERE userid = '$fo->hostid' ORDER by          subjectid DESC LIMIT 25";
          $query= mysql_query($sql);        
          if($query){
              if(mysql_num_rows($query)> 0){

                  while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){

                      $output[]=$row;
                 }
              }
           }
      }      
   return $output ;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. I think the problem is that you are selecting data for each user individually rather than using an `IN(...)` clause for your where condition and selecting alll rows at once, but I am not sure exactly how you are looking to display your results.  Can you clarify this?

Comment: this is my shown subjects numbers with users :

Comment: user1 (sub no 4 and sub no 3)user2(sub no 1) but user1 have (sub no 2) too but its dessapear  not in order right now ? < this is example to explain ..

Comment: i need to press view more btn to take the last subject id in the example it will be no 1 ?

Comment: my question is why sub no 2 dessapear ? what i need is sub no 1 to be dessapear untill i press the btn ..

Comment: Can you simply update your question? You are talking about a "Show More" button for which there is not context here.  There really is nothing here to show how you are using the data returned from this function.

Comment: hmm no , i think my problem is with the object looping .. like if i remove the object and put a single user id like userid=1  it will retrieve all the subjects DESC and i can put the limit so it will stop loading in that limit .. and pressing the btn will continue loading .. but this not work to me with many users only with single user :(